# HttPost rest webservice response message help

Tags: apex

Hi i need help with my response message when inserting records with webservice, I need to have 3 response message. 1 where in If all the products have no error, 1 for the error message of each record and then if one of the records inserted has an error. I used a wrapper when inserting records because i can insert many records of one parent in one call.

Can someone help me figure this out.

This is my code

```
@restResource(urlMapping='/merchandise/*')
```

global with sharing class buyProduct{

```
global with sharing class Wrapper1{

    public string CustomerNumber {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper2> wrapper2 {get;set;}
}
global with sharing class Wrapper2{
    public decimal Quantity {get;set;}
    public string ProductCode{get;set;}
    public date StartDate;

}

global class ResponseWrapper{
    public String Status;
    public String Message;
    public String ErrorCode;
    public string CustomerNumber;
}


//global static boolean isNotNullorEmpty(Object str) {
//return str != null || !String.isBlank(String.valueOf(str));
//}


@httpPost
global static List<ResponseWrapper> getID(Wrapper1 test){

    boolean selector = False;

    Map<String,Account> CNnumber = new Map<String,Account>();
    List<Account> accList = [Select Id, Customer_Number__c , Account_Credit__c from Account];

    for(Account acn : accList){
        CNnumber.put(acn.Customer_Number__c, acn);
    }

    List<ResponseWrapper> responseList = new List<ResponseWrapper>();



    Wrapper2 wrp = new Wrapper2();


    Map<String,Product__c> prdCode = new Map<String,Product__c>();

    List<Product__c> prd = [Select Id, ProductCode__c, Quantity__c, type__c, Price__c from Product__c];

    for(Product__c pc : prd){
        prdCode.put(pc.ProductCode__c, pc);
    }

    decimal totalPrice2 = 0;
    decimal TotalPrice3 = 0;


     Account acc = CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber);
    List<OrderProduct__c> opList = new List<OrderProduct__c>();
    for(Wrapper2 soW : test.wrapper2){
        ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper();

        if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode) == null && soW.ProductCode !=null){
            response.Status = 'Error';
            response.Message = 'Invalid Product Code';
            response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
            response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
            responseList.add(response);
            selector = True;


        }



        else if(soW.ProductCode == null){
            response.Status = 'Error';
            response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Product Code]';
            response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
            response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
            responseList.add(response);
            selector = True;
        }




        else if (soW.Quantity == null){
            response.Status = 'Error';
            response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Quantity]';
            response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
            response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
            responseList.add(response);
            selector = True;
        }

        else if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Quantity__c < soW.Quantity){
            response.Status = 'Error';
            response.Message = 'Not Enough Stock for your Order';
            response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
            response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
            responseList.add(response);
            selector = True;
        }

        else if (prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'Subscription' && soW.StartDate == null){
            response.Status = 'Error';
            response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Start Date  ]';
            response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
            response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
            responseList.add(response);
            selector = True; 
        }


        //Validation for One time payment


        else if(soW.ProductCode != null && soW.Quantity != null){
            OrderProduct__c op = new OrderProduct__c();
            //op.Subscription_Order__c = so.Id;
            op.Subscription_Product__c = prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).id;
            op.Quantity__c = soW.Quantity;
            op.Start_Date__c = soW.StartDate;
            if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Type__c == 'One Time Payment'){
                op.Subscription__c = 'No';
            }



            Decimal totalPrice = prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Price__c * soW.Quantity;


            if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'One Time Payment' && totalPrice > CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber).Account_Credit__c)   
            {
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'insufficient  Credit for this type of Product';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                selector = True; 
               system.debug('#####OGVALIDATION' + response.Message);
                system.debug('#####' + totalPrice);
            }





            if(!Selector){

                if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'One Time Payment' ){
                    TotalPrice2 = TotalPrice2 + TotalPrice;
                    if(TotalPrice2 < acc.Account_Credit__c){

                          response.Status = 'Order On Hold because of one of the Products';
                response.Message = 'Successful';
                response.CustomerNumber = test.CustomerNumber; 
                response.ErrorCode = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                System.debug('#####TOTALPRICE2' + totalPrice2);
                System.debug('#####VALIDATION1' + response.Message);
                opList.add(op);
                    }
                    else{
                         response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'insufficient  Credit for this type of Product';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                system.debug('#####TOTALPRICE2' + totalPrice2);
                SYSTEM.debug('#####VALIDATION2' + response.Message);
                Selector = True;
                    }

                    //opList.add(op);
                }

                else if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'Subscription' ){
                         response.Status = 'Order On Hold because of one of the Products';
                response.Message = 'Successful';
                response.CustomerNumber = test.CustomerNumber; 
                response.ErrorCode = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                    opList.add(op);
                }
                else{
                    TotalPrice3 = TotalPrice3 + TotalPrice;
                    opList.add(op);
                }

            }

        }

    }


    System.debug('#####' + TotalPrice2);
    if(Selector){
        return responseList;
    }
    else{
        ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper();

        Subscription_Order__c so = new Subscription_Order__c();
        so.Account__c = CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber).id;
        insert so;
        System.debug('#####1' + so.Id);




        for(OrderProduct__c op : opList){
            op.Subscription_Order__c = so.Id;
        }

        if(TotalPrice2 < Acc.Account_Credit__c){
            acc.account_credit__c =     acc.account_credit__c - totalPrice2;    
            update acc;
        }

          /*
                response.Status = 'Product Bought';
                response.Message = 'Successful';
                response.CustomerNumber = test.CustomerNumber; 
                response.ErrorCode = Null ;
                responseList.add(response);
            */


        System.debug('#####' + opList);
        insert opList;
        return responseList;
    }





}
```

}

My problem right now is if all of the products inserted has no error it still throw a response message of `Order On Hold`

Your help is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed you are using `insert opList;` Instead you should use `Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(opList, false);` and iterate over `srList` to get the details about each inserted record. See the [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) below from Salesforce.

```
// Create two accounts, one of which is missing a required field
Account[] accts = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name='Account1'),
    new Account()};
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(accts, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```